# To make a decent to high quality mobile version of my website?

Tags: java, android, html, mobile, web

I'm new to Stack Overflow, but I asked a question last night regarding some code and it was answered just over night. I'm very glad I finally signed up here. Anyway, on to my question...

I need to make a mobile version of my website [[www.famebyname.us]](http://www.famebyname.us/)

I am using Dreamweaver CS6, and my intention with the domain is to turn it into an online nightclub/chat/music type thing. It has a long way to go, but it's basic for now and can do for basic communication. I'd like to make a mobile version of it. But instead of just going forth with that, I thought I'd ask here if anyone could share some experience designing mobile sites [IE button sizes, content alignment, and above all how to keep the smartchatbox working for the mobile device while being size friendly.]

On a site note I'm going to be using the java code below to redirect users with a screen size under 699px to the mobile version aif anyone has any better recommendation for this type of redirection, I'm open to new ideas.

```
<!--if (screen.width <= 699) { document.location = "mobile.html"; } //-->
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing all the coding for mobile site. Why not use the framework? There are many frameworks out there that support mobile friendly site. All you need to do is setup files and start calling them in div tags as classes and it will do all by itself. You would need to understand tho how it works.

Checkout this frameworks :

```
Bootstrap
Foundation
Ui kit
Semantic UI
```

Dont reinvent the wheel when you such powerful frameworks to help you.

Comment: May I suggest using Bootstrap if you are new to these frameworks. There are a ton of resources out there in the form of StackOverflow questions and the like. I, personally, found it to be the easiest to learn.